# Can I use gdb to skip a line without having to type line numbers?

Tags: gdb

I know I can use `jump` to set the program counter to a specific line and so I can skip one or more lines (or execute some lines again). Can I easily just skip the next line without having to enter line numbers?

This would be very convenient to "comment out" something at run time.

Comment: Related: more general stuff about using `jump` (e.g. that it's only safe inside the current function, and only if you compiled with `-O0`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116632/is-it-possible-to-jump-skip-in-gdb-debugger/46043760#46043760

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
jump +1
```

jumps to the next line line i.e. skipping the current line. You may also want to combine it with `tbreak +1` to set a temporary breakpoint at the jump target.

See http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html for more ways of expressing locations with gdb.

Note that without a breakpoint `gdb` is likely to continue execution normally instead of jumping. So if jumping doesn't seem to work, make sure you set a breakpoint at the destination.

Comment: Pretty obvious, but thanks! Works great in Xcode using breakpoints with Debugger Command.

Comment: It should be noted that this works in LLDB as well. :)

Comment: If you're working directly in asm, you can jump to the instruction that you want by issuing a `j addr` where `addr` is the address where you want to jump to.

Comment: Note that this is only going to work as a source-level skip if you compiled with `-O0`.  Any optimization will make it unsafe to skip around.

Comment: Also note that this only works reliable with an address in the first place, `jump +1` will lead to "unreasonable jump request" if the code is in a file that is used multiple times (most likely in common headers that have actual code).

Answer (score 29):

I have the following in my `.gdbinit` config file:

```
define skip
    tbreak +1
    jump +1
end
```

So just type `skip` in gdb to skip a line.

Comment: How to parametrize it to "skip(N)" ?

Comment: @p2rkw. You can replace '1' with $arg0, as explained here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html. Be aware that I would not use the name 'skip' anymore, because it became a GDB function  (allowing to skip source files while stepping through your code).

Comment: @Trass3r True. I mention this in the comment above.

Comment: As `skip` is an internal command since many years (to skip *stepping into* functions (defined by several options including source file) during `step`, this means: they are still executed just "as if" you'd have done a `nexti` on the calling place), it is likely useful to give this another name, maybe jump-lines-and-stop?

Answer (score 5):

To Skip Any Numbers of Lines during Execution:

```
[Current Position -- in GDB] Line N
.......... // Lines To Skip
..........
..........
[Line To Execute - After Jumping] Line M
```

Put a Breakpoint on Line M:

```
gdb$b M
```

Jump To Line M:

```
gdb$jump M
```