# Is it possible to "jump"/"skip" in GDB debugger?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Is it possible to jump to some location/address in the code/executable while debugging in GDB ?

Let say I have something similar to the following

```
int main()
{
  caller_f1() {  

   f1();  // breakpoint  
   f2() } // want to skip f2() and jump 

  caller_f2() { // jump to this this location ??       
   f1();  
   f2(); }  
}
```

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 Question is 4 years old at this point. Let it go. Thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be a jump command which is exactly what you are looking for:

http://idlebox.net/2010/apidocs/gdb-7.0.zip/gdb_18.html#SEC163

Updated link:
http://web.archive.org/web/20140101193811/http://idlebox.net/2010/apidocs/gdb-7.0.zip/gdb_18.html#SEC163

Answer (score 23):

To resume execution at a new address, use `jump` (short form: `j`):

```
jump LINENUM
jump *ADDRESS
```

[The GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping) suggests using `tbreak` (temporary breakpoint) before jumping.

The linenum can be any [`linespec`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Linespec-Locations.html#Linespec-Locations) expression, like `+1` for the next line.

See [@gospes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037308/can-i-use-gdb-to-skip-a-line-without-having-to-type-line-numbers/36505832#36505832) on a related question for a handy `skip` macro that does exactly that.

---

**Using `jump` is only "safe" in un-optimized code (`-O0`)**, and even then only within the current function.  It *only* modifies the program counter; it doesn't change any other registers or memory.

Only `gcc -O0` compiles each source statement (or line?) into an independent block of instructions that loads variable values from memory and stores results.  This lets you modify variable values with a debugger at any breakpoint, and makes `jump`ing between lines in the machine code work like jumping between lines in the C source.

This is part of why `-O0` makes such slow code: not only does the compiler not spend time optimizing, it is required to make slow code that spills/reloads everything after every statement to support asynchronous modification of variables and even program-counter.  (Store/reload latency is about 5 cycles on a typical x86, so a 1 cycle `add` takes 6 cycles in `-O0` builds).

[gcc's manual suggests using `-Og`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for the usual edit-compile-debug cycle, but even that light level of optimization will break `jump` and async modification of variables.  If you don't want to do that while debugging, it's a good choice, especially for projects where `-O0` runs so slowly that it's a problem.

---

**To set program-counter / instruction-pointer to a new address without resuming**, you can also use this:

```
set $pc = 0x4005a5
```

Copy/paste addresses from the disassembly window (`layout asm` / `layout reg`).

This is equivalent to `tbreak` + `jump`, but you can't use line numbers, only instruction addresses.  (And you don't get a warning + confirmation-request for jumping outside the current function).

Then you can `stepi` from there.  `$pc` is a generic gdb name for whatever the register is really called in the target architecture.  e.g. RIP in x86-64.  (See also the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for asm debugging tips for gdb.)

Comment: Nice explanation. Is there any article with examples of what could happen when jumping around in optimized code? Like smashing the stack. I can't imagine it not crashing or doing weird things all the time but I remember it was usually fine in practice.

Comment: @Trass3r:  Not that I know of; I haven't written one and haven't gone looking; I've never wanted to try doing that.  Usually functions do all their stack allocation up front, on function entry.  Stack cleanup after a call with pushed stack args is often part of the same "block" as the call, so jumping around won't break it up.  (Unless you jump to arbitrary instructions instead of still to C source lines.)

Comment: What is likely is breaking some logic like constant-propagation or other invariants.  e.g. don't expect re-running the `i++` in a loop body to work if there's also a `ptr++` and they're optimized into one.  Or jumping into a loop would very likely not have run the loop setup and totally break.  Basically anything involving register values is likely to break.