# How to skip some lines in the GDB debugger?

Tags: c

How can I skip a line in the GDB debugger?

Comment: What do you mean? **Step** to the next line, once you've hit a breakpoint? Cause the line to never be executed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037308/can-i-use-gdb-to-skip-a-line-without-having-to-type-line-numbers

Answer (score 15):

You may find these links interesting :

[GDB Tutorial - Main commands](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Debug.html#tth_sEc4.3)

[Another tutorial](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs331/gdbtutorial.html)

In short, you can use :

- `next` to execute the current line and directly go to the next one (if the line is a function call, it doesn't step into the function),
- `step` to execute the current line (if it's a function call, it enters the function and stops at its first statement),
- `until X` to execute the code and stop on line X
- `b X` and then `run` or `continue`, to set a breakpoint on line X and execute the code until line X is reached.

---

If you really want to **skip** a line, thus stepping to the next one but NOT executing it, you can use `jump X` (X being a line number). Be careful and use breakpoints, because using `jump` will make the debugger resume code execution from line X.

Answer (score 4):

several ways

> next

to step a line

> until 1234

to continue until the line 1234.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip execution of some lines, you can manually alter program counter and continue execution