# Is there a way to get GDB to skip/ignore an instruction?

Tags: gdb

I'm running through some assembly code in GDB trying to debug my program and I'd like to see what happens if I ignore an instruction entirely, is there a way to do this? (skip past it to the next line without executing it) without having to edit the source code and comment out the function and then recompile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037308/can-i-use-gdb-to-skip-a-line gives a correct solution. The command is `jump`.

Answer (score 8):

> is there a way to do this

Sure: `jump *0x1234` will jump to instruction at address `0x1234`.

> skip past it to the next line without executing it

"Next line" and assembly debugging rarely go together. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037308/can-i-use-gdb-to-skip-a-line) answer shows, you can skip a line as well.